# How to add and remove dynamically subtitle in video with Gstreamer in a C program

Tags: c, video, gstreamer, subtitle

For a school project, I must do a video reader with gstreamer and gtk, **without playbin2**. 
In this reader, I must add and remove subtitles when video is reading.

Currently I use `decodebin` to play all formats but impossible to add subtitle with it. 
I successful have dynamic subtitles with oggdemux, but this solutions work only for ogg format. So, I search others solutions with decodebin.

I tried many solutions:

### Decodebin and subtitles

First, I tried to add directly subtitles gstreamer elements to video queue. I precise that my program works without subtitles gstreamer elements (audio/video is playing).

```
// Creation of many elements of gstreamer
data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("video-player");  
source_media = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc",     "file-source");    
demuxer  = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin",   "decodebin");
// AUDIO -----
sink_audio = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");
queue_audio = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "thread-audio");

// VIDEO -----
sink_video  = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "video-output");    
queue_video = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "thread-video");

// SUBTITLE -----    
source_sub = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "sub-source");
subparse = gst_element_factory_make("subparse", "subparse");
textoverlay = gst_element_factory_make ("subtitleoverlay", "subtitleoverlay");

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source_media), "location", argv[1], NULL);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline),
                     source_media, demuxer,
                     queue_audio, sink_audio,  
                     queue_video, sink_video,
                     source_sub, subparse, textoverlay, 
                     NULL);

gst_element_link (source_media, demuxer);            
gst_element_link_many (queue_audio, sink_audio, NULL);
g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), queue_audio);
gst_element_link_many (queue_video, textoverlay, sink_video, NULL);
g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), queue_video);    
gst_element_link_many (source_sub, subparse, textoverlay, NULL);
```

### A new pipeline for subtitles

Second, I tried to create another pipeline which contains only subtitles gstreamer elements

```
// Creation of many elements of gstreamer
data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("video-player");  
date.subtitle = gst_pipeline_new ("subtitles");
source_media = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc",     "file-source");    
demuxer  = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin",   "decodebin");
// AUDIO -----
sink_audio = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio-output");
queue_audio = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "thread-audio");

// VIDEO -----
sink_video  = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "video-output");    
queue_video = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "thread-video");

// SUBTITLE -----    
source_sub = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "sub-source");
subparse = gst_element_factory_make("subparse", "subparse");
textoverlay = gst_element_factory_make ("subtitleoverlay", "subtitleoverlay");

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source_media), "location", argv[1], NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source_sub), "location", argv[2], NULL);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline),
                     source_media, demuxer,
                     queue_audio, sink_audio,  
                     queue_video, sink_video, NULL);

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN (data.subtitle),
                 source_sub, subparse, textoverlay,
                 NULL);

gst_element_link (source_media, demuxer);  
gst_element_link (source_sub, subparse);

gst_element_link_many (queue_audio, sink_audio, NULL);
g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), queue_audio);
gst_element_link_many (queue_video, textoverlay, sink_video, NULL);
g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), queue_video);    
gst_element_link_many (source_sub, subparse, textoverlay, NULL);

if (gst_element_link_pads(subparse, "src", textoverlay, "subtitle-sink")) {
    perror("***error: Pads couldn't be linked\n");
}
```

Comment: Hello from the past. Nice topic. I found solution reading your question. Thank you. But can i ask something, please? You are registering callback function to detect pads in video file. Can it be done before pipeline start? For example, make filesrc and demuxer. Then link them. And run "initialization". So, demuxer now know how many pads he will have. The think i want to avoid, is splitted code, when one peace of pipeline done in one function (read from file), another in another (decode and play), but all linked together in third place.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add :

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source_sub), "location", argv[2], NULL);
```

in your first solution and it should work (except if you don't give subtitles, in this case you should check whether they're present or not and link/unlink the elements).

Then to activate/deactivate the subtitles during playback, you'll have to play with the "silent" property from subtitleoverlay.

Good luck !

Comment: Hi ! 
Thanks for your answer,

Since I post this question, I resolved my problem; 

In fact, I used the silent property, and it's work correctly. 

Thanks again, and have a nice day :-)